# How to use the same letter for an int and cin keyboard input C++

Tags: c++, console-application

Hi I want to use the same letter for an int and cin keyboard input so when I enter in the new number it changes the number in the cell when I enter the score in with the keyboard sample code take into account i'm still a beginner and still learning:

```
int h = 0; 
cout << " _______________________" << endl; 
cout << "|chelsea fc |"<< h << "|" << endl; 
cout << "|___________|__________|" << endl; 

string h = ""; 

cout << "Type here to add score to table" << endl; 
getline(cin, h); 

cout << "You added the score " << h << " to the table" << endl;
```

Comment: Why do you want to use the same name for two different variables? You can't do this.

Comment: So I can change the value from 0 to another value but don't know what I'm doing have you got a better idea?

Comment: How would either you or the compiler know which variable you mean when you write `h`?

Comment: LOL - *don't know what I'm doing*

Comment: You can have symbols with different type and the same name in *different scope*, but not in the same scope, that's simply not possible. Also, consider naming your variables to show meaning, that makes the code more maintainable and easier to read and understand by other, and by "other" I mean *you* in a few months time.

Comment: So basic I want to initialise the value to 0 and then be able to change it from keyboard input could you please guide me how to do this i'm aware i'm doing it wrong but not sure what the solution is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like this:

```
int score = 0; 
cout << " _______________________" << endl; 
cout << "|chelsea fc |"<< score << "|" << endl; 
cout << "|___________|__________|" << endl; 

cout << "Type here to add score to table" << endl; 
cin >> score;

cout << "You added the score " << score << " to the table" << endl;
```

Remember that when reading numbers and strings, using the input operator `>>` reads *and discards* leading white-space in the input, so even if there is a newline in the input buffer after the input of the score, if you attempt to read a new number or a string that newline will simply be ignored.

Comment: Thank you so much I probably sounded so stupid but I'm still getting to grips with the language thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to write a function that outputs the score table based on an integer. Something like this:

```
void write_table(int h) {
    cout << " _______________________" << endl; 
    cout << "|chelsea fc |"<< h << "|" << endl; 
    cout << "|___________|__________|" << endl; 
}
```

Call that function after you ask the user for input.